# how can i print onto the screen which numbers are the same in each list

Tags: list, python-3.x, random

```
List1 = []
```

called List1
    import random

```
for n in range(1000):
    y =  random.randrange(0,100000)
    List1.append(y)

    List2 = []

for n1 in range(1000):
    y1 =  random.randrange(0,100000)
    List2.append(y1)
```

first list, i want to see those numbers in #

Comment: Use a `Counter`...

Comment: thank you very much Willem Van Onsem for editing the question so it appears more clean and easier to read

Comment: how would I use a counter can u give me an example

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5829377/67579).

Comment: no I asked the question wrong what I meant was not to count how many times and item occurs but count which item occurs

Comment: `for item1, item2 in zip(List1, List2):
   if item1 == item2:
    print(item1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) and [counters](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html):

Numbers in List2 not in List1:

```
set_of_different_numbers = set(List2) - set(List1)
```

Occurences of numbers in List2:

```
from collections import Counter
occurence_count = Counter(List2)
```

Occurences of numbers in List2 that are not in List1:

```
occurence_in_disjunction = Counter([l for l in List2 if l in set_of_different_numbers])
```

Comment: what would I then print to get the numbers in both lists on screen ted ?

Comment: what do you mean by " get the numbers in both lists" ? you can just print `occurence_in_disjunction` to see the number of occurences of numbers in `List2` that are not in `List1`.